# Android App for ELM 327 that allows to reset codes for Cadillac CTS

Tags: obd-ii, cadillac, elm-327

On my Cadillac I get engine light to come up because I have changed my petrol cap and sensor is malfunctioning. I got myself [wifi ELM 327 OBD-2 reader](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/251678845583?adgroupid=16885268106&hlpht=true&hlpv=2&rlsatarget=pla-124272975426&adtype=pla&ff3=1&lpid=122&poi=&ul_noapp=true&limghlpsr=true&ff19=0&device=c&chn=ps&campaignid=270621186&crdt=0&ff12=67&ff11=ICEP3.0.0-L&ff14=122&viphx=1&ops=true&ff13=80), and by using my laptop I managed to get RPM of engine - it must work. However full version of application costs ~150$ and functionality for error code resetting is not provided in free version. I then tried looking for Android app that would allow me to reset error codes, but after 2 hours of installing tens of apps (including upgrading to paid versions up to 10$) I finally gave up.

**Does anyone know Android app that would work for Cadillac CTS?** Would prefer free (but would be perfectly happy with paid if not ridiculously expensive).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a software recommendation

Comment: @Zaid I'm torn. I think it could use a broader title, but I think it is on topic because the software is being used as an intermediate tool, so the question is ultimately still about working on an engine. I'm withholding my vote for now.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't list the apps you tried, but Torque (http://torque-bhp.com/) is what I am using (on a different vehicle); however, the Cadillac CTS forums has numerous posts on folks using the app with success.

Comment: Hi Phil, I tried Torque free version, it shows icons on top that it has connected to the system, but when I accelerate rpm meter does not move, so I don't think it works. Thanks.